# String format - French accents

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have an issue with scraping some string data from Wikipedia. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "city"
    start_urls = ['https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_Belgique_par_population']

    def parse(self, response):
        for city in response.css('table.wikitable td a::text').getall():
            if city == '2':
                pass
            elif city == '3':
                pass
            else:        
                yield {
                    'cities': city + ', BE'
                }
```

The issue is that the strings are in french and some cities contains "è" or "é". When I export them to a json file, a word like "Liège" is exported like this "Li\u00e8ge". How can I turn those strings into french letters ?

Comment: Which python version do you use? With Python3, `print('Li\u00e8ge')` gives `Liège`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to convert them into french.
They are one and the same.
You can check them in ipython as  follows

```
In [1]: l2 = 'Liège'

In [2]: l2
Out[2]: 'Li\xc3\xa8ge'

In [3]: print(l2)
Liège
```

Answer (score 1):

A character is the smallest possible component of a text. 'A','B','C', etc are all different characters. So are ‘È’ and ‘Í’. Characters are abstractions and vary depending on the language or context you are talking about.
The Unicode standard describes how characters are represented by **code points**.
A code point is an integer value usually denoted in Base 16. In the standard, a code point is written using the notation `U+12CA` to mean the character with value `0*12ca` 4810 decimal). 
The Unicode standard contains a lot of tables listing character and their corresponding code points.

```
In [14]: a='\xc3\xa8'

In [15]: b='è'

In [16]: if a==b:
   ....:     print(True)
   ....:     
True
```